# I have to run this script multiple times. Is there a script I can write that will run everything at once?

Tags: ruby, task

The script I have to run:

```
Li = LineItem.find ##### 
li.rental_period = ### 
li.save!
```

I have 800 line item numbers to run this for. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it the same rental_period for all of them? Is the rental_period something you need to initialize or just a string?

Comment: Same rental period different line item numbers.

Comment: Should this be tagged with Rails or ActiveRecord? This looks like more than vanilla Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

If they all have different rental periods:

```
line_item_numbers.each do |num|
  li = LineItem.find(num)
  li.rental_period = custom_rental_period
  li.save!
end
```

If they're all the same, you can just do an `update_all`:

```
LineItem.where(id: line_item_numbers).update_all(rental_period: custom_rental_period)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line_item_number_string = line_item_number.join(',')    
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE line_items SET rental_period=<value> WHERE id IN (#{line_item_number_string})")
```

Answer (score 0):

while loop

```
a = 0
b = 4 #this loop will run 4 times 
while a < b 

 Li = LineItem.find ##### 
 li.rental_period = ### 
 li.save!

 a += 1 #adds one to a
end
```

This is pretty much the same as the first answer, just written in a different way. I find that noobs to ruby can understand this a little easier.

OR

```
def go
 Li = LineItem.find ##### 
 li.rental_period = ### 
 li.save!
end
```

then call "go" in your code to execute your syntax

```
go
```

thats how you call go